# Авторизация только по логину для пользователей

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, passport

Всем доброго времени суток.
Стоит задача реализовать сервис, на который юзер будет попадать имея логин (как правило сгенерированный админом), а администратор будет заходить под логином и паролем. Соответственно после авторизации у админа должна быть своя страница, а у пользователя своя. С этим в принципе все ясно, а вот с первой частью не очень...
Суть вопроса: подскажите пожалуйста какими способами можно реализовать авторизацию описанную выше? Стэк: Mongo DB или Redis (пока определяюсь), Express, React JS. 
Как я это вижу: у админа будет панелька, в которой он будет добавлять логины пользователей, которые будут сохраняться в базу, затем, если логин в базе есть, то пользователь может войти, если нет - то нет. 
Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, стоит создать таблицу users, в которой будут находится login и uid (если нужен) и прочая инфа пользователей (кроме admin). Администратор на странице имеет форму добавления пользователя (содержимое в зависимости от того, что надо вбить в базу + login).

При авторизации пользователей идёт запрос в базу

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE login='...'
```

и если он возвращает не 0 или ошибку, то авторизация проходит успешно, в базу записывается ip (на усмотрение) и в куки прописывается login.
При проверке пользователя на авторизированность просматривается этот куки и выводится соответствующая страница или страница входа.

Решил написать пример

login.php

```
<?php
//Подключаем скрипт с проверкой логина
include_once 'login_lib.php';

//Проверяем, была ли отправлена форма
if(isset($_POST['login']){
  //Обрабатываем переменную, для защиты
  $login = trim(striptags($_POST['login']));
  //Проверяем
  if(isLogin($login)){
    //Пишем куки
    cookie("login", $login, 3600 * 24 * 30, "/");
    //Меняем заголовок для перехода на предыдущую страницу
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    //Выходим из скрипта
    exit();
  }
}
//Если форма не была введена или логина нет в базе
//будет загружена страница входа
include_once 'login.html';
?>
```

login_lib.php

```
<?php
//Подключаемся к MySQL
$db = mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass");
//Выбираем базу
$db->select_db("site");

//Функция проверки существования аргумента в таблице пользователей
function isLogin($login){
    //В результате запроса получаем кол-во записей с логином
    //соответствующем аргументу
    $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE login='$login'");
    //Возвращаем итог сравнения этого кол-ва с нулём
    //(если кол-во больше 0, то вернёт истину)
    return $result.fetch_row()[0] > 0;
}
?>
```

Код в начале каждой страницы, требующей входа

```
<?php
//Подключаем скрипт с проверкой логина
include_once 'login_lib.php';
//Проверяем, существует ли нужная куки
//и существует ли она в базе
//Так же значение проходит через защиту
if(!isset($_COOKIE['login']) || !isLogin(striptags($_COOKIE['login']))){
    //Если нет, то меняем заголовок на страницу входа
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}/login.php");
    //И выходим из скрипта
    exit();
}

//Иначе подключаем саму страницу
include 'index.html';
?>
```

С остальным можно разобраться и самому

Comment: я вам конечно благодарен, но написан же стек технологий..
но изучу, спасибо

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn я извиняюсь) Просто вместо псевдокода написал на php) По крайней мере будет считать так)

Comment: Часть, которая должна быть на каждой странице может быть написана на js 
 с ajax get запросом в самом начале, а куки выставлять при входе можно точно так же запросами ajax

Comment: спасибо, суть в принципе я понимал, я больше хотел услышать в ответах готовые решения (boilerplate) на js. но вам правда огромное спасибо

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn если хотите, могу расписать примерно на ajax